# get form field value from collection loop

Tags: ajax, forms, loops, collections, coldfusion

I am looping over a collection (form) and testing for 'attachedFile' in the form field name. On success, I want to add the form field value to an array. Currently, I am only getting the form field name and not the value.

```
<cfloop collection="#FORM#" item="field">
    <cfif FindNoCase('attachedFile',field) IS 1>
        <cfset fileNamesArray[fileNamesIndex] = field>
        <cfset fileNamesIndex = fileNamesIndex + 1>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

I tried setting the array at index [whatever] to #form.field# but that results in an error (undefined). Any ideas how to get my value inside this loop? Thanks.

Comment: FYI, there's `ArrayAppend()` that you can use if you're just inserting things into an array.

Comment: FWIW - The error was probably because you did not initialize the index variable before the loop. However, as Henry mentioned, `arrayAppend` is much simpler ie `arrayAppend(fieldNamesAray, FORM[field]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<cfloop collection="#Form#" item="field">
    <cfset currentFieldName  = field>
    <cfset currentFieldValue = Form[field]>
</cfloop>
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fe2.html

Or if you prefer the script style, and you're using CF9, use the for-in loop

```
<cfscript>
    for (field in Form)
    {
        currentFieldName  = field;
        currentFieldValue = Form[field];
    }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: How would I set the cfdump equal to a variable?

Comment: the cfdump is just a way to illustrate to you that you can access the value of the field using `Form[field]`.  To set it to a var, use `<cfset x = Form[field]`.

Answer (score 1):

In Coldfusion 10 or Railo 4, you can use the [filter()](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/#filter) function of the [Underscore.cfc library](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/) in cfscript like so:

```
var fileNamesArray = _.filter(form, function (value, field) {
    return FindNoCase('attachedFile', field);
});
```

The filter() function returns an array of values that pass the truth test, which in this case is FindNoCase(...).

Using functional style programming results in a more elegant and expressive solution.

(Note: I wrote Underscore.cfc)